# @JmsListener issue with durable subscription

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I am using Spring's `@JmsListener` (spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar)  for receiving messages from ActiveMQ using the below code:

```
@Component
public class TopicSubscriber {
    @JmsListener(destination="xyz.topic1", subscription="xyz_topic_durable_subscription")
    public void send(Product product) {     
        System.out.println(" reveived message ***"+product);
    }
}
```

As per the Spring API's documentation (link given below), the above code should create a durable subscription with subscription name as `xyz_topic_durable_subscription`:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html#subscription--

But, the issue is that **the above code creates only Non-Durable subscription** which I could find by monitoring the ActiveMQ using admin console (added screenshot below, look for 'xyz.topic1' Destination under 'Active Non-Durable Topic Subscribers' section).

Are there any changes to be made in the code to make the durable subscription ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to configure the ListenerContainerFactory appropriately:

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
    factory.setClientId("jmsDemo");
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
}
```

There interesting part is here:

```
    factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
    factory.setClientId("jmsDemo");
```

Now when you enter the ActiveMQ WebConsole you should see this:

[image: ActiveMQ WebConsole showing one Durable Topic Subscriber]

Answer (score 5):

In the answer marked as correct above, the code:

```
factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
factory.setSubscriptionDurable(true);
factory.setClientId("jmsDemo");
```

must come after

```
configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
```

or you will lose those settings.

Comment: Which class is this 'configurer'? Can you please share more details? Thanks
configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

Comment: I got the sample code from https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer&method=configure

Comment: 'configurer' is the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer that is passed into the method as a parameter

Comment: I found that I also had to name the bean `jmsListenerContainerFactory` to override the default.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to configure the listener container factory to create a container for [durable subscriptions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/config/AbstractJmsListenerContainerFactory.html#setSubscriptionDurable-java.lang.Boolean-).